# Should I handle a lot of UI on one screen with fragments? [android]

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, fragment

I'm new to android development and I want to know how to properly use fragments  and activities. As far as I've learned it's better to make single activity applications and mine is just that. However, I have a lot of UI on my screen. The app is supposed to be a simple 3D editor with basic functionalities where I have a big scene and lots of UI around it (similar to any 3D editor). Is it okay to group parts of the UI in fragments and handle each part's buttons and etc. there. I don't know if this is a good way to do it because I understood that fragments are supposed to be reusable content while I'm using it more as a singleton, where each fragment appears only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different people have different opinions about how many activities should be used in an app. However, with that being said most do generally agree that you should have one main activity and everything else should be a fragment. The whole idea behind doing this is to make you code more modular and reusable (just like you said). So one potential way to tackle your problem could be grouping content into certain fragments. So, for example, you could have a fragment for a title bar, tool bar, a fragment for the editor space, etc. It is pretty normal to have multiple fragments in the same screen.

Hopefully this helps!